# How to make Expandable UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two arrays, first is for person's name and second is person's details with different sizes.

And I want to show this info in `UITableViewCell`.
When the view appears it shows list of persons and when tapping on particular person, the cell should expand and show that person's detail info from a second array.

How do I show this info in a single view based application without using any other templates?

Comment: Did you look at the list of related questions to your question? There are several listed that already answer this question. Please don't post duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

When any of the cell is clicked you can increase the height of that particular to display all details, you can do this as follows:

> 1. Initially all cells will have same height so in heightForRowAtIndexPath will return same height say 40.
> 2. When user clicks on any cell, store that index path in some variable and call reloadData for tableView, which will call
>      heightForRowAtIndexPath, in this you check for selected cell index
>      path and return height say 100, which will display user info also.

Hope this works for your requirement.